# Docker initialize host mounted volume

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I want to create a docker image for a software that need a persistent data volume which has to be initialized with some specific files and folders and I think you could reach that be creating a volume in the dockerfile after the creation of the files.

But my problem is, that I want to access the files direct from the host system, but it seems that there is no way to initialize the host folder like the named volume would be.

Does anybody know a way to achieve such an initialization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I now found a solution for this problem. The point is that only named volumes are initialized in this way, but, at least with docker-compose, you can specify a named volume which refers to a given folder on host and will be initialized:

```
volumes:
  my_volume:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: ./data_volume_dir
      o: bind
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct here, [`bind mounts`](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) are different here to [(named) `volumes`](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes)

> - New **volumes** can have their content pre-populated by a container.

I.e. there is no built-in mechanism in `docker` to automatically populate the contents of a folder from a container bind-mounted into it, but a few workarounds:

- use a custom `volume` plugin, in this case e.g. [`local-persist`](https://github.com/MatchbookLab/local-persist)
- manually copy the contents via an `entrypoint` script - the original content then has to be accessible under another path within the container since it will be shadowed by the `bind mount`
- with `docker-compose`: define a dedicated service to populate the volume; you may use [`service profiles`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles) so this service will not be started automatically with `docker-compose up`